# How to understand and discriminate pattern match and tuple?

Tags: haskell

I am a novice of `Haskell`, and get a little confused with pattern matching and tuples. E.g., in [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#where):

> You can also use where bindings to pattern match! We could have rewritten the where section of our previous function as:

```
...  
where bmi = weight / height ^ 2  
      (skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
```

The `(skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)` is a pattern match, but it is also a tuple, right? How can I understand and discriminate pattern match and tuple?

Comment: All constructors, not just the constructors for tuples, can appear in patterns. You can discriminate between patterns and expressions by seeing which side of an `=` symbol (in a function) they occur on - the left hand side is a pattern, and the right hand side is an expression. The semantics of patterns can be found in the [Haskell Report](https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell2010.pdf), s3.17.

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching is used to name variables which are set in a specific pattern.
Here, you can say that "the variables `skinny` `normal` and `fat` represent values of a tuple which is equal to `(18.5, 25.0, 30.0)`"

You can use pattern matching in other cases, such as lists.

```
first_element [] = error "Empty list"
first_element (x:rest) = x
```

Here the pattern is either an empty list `[]` or a value `x` followed by the rest of the given list.

If you type in GHCI

```
let (x:xs) = [2, 3, 4]
```

Then by pattern matching `x` will have the value `2` and xs the value `[3, 4]`.

Tuples are just "boxes" which can contain multiple values of multiple types.
A point can be represented as a tuple of type `(Double, Double)`.

You can construct any tuple of any type. In your example, `(18.5, 25.0, 30.0)` may be of type `(Double, Double, Double)`

Answer (score 1):

In Haskell, patterns and expressions largely share the same internal syntax, the difference is **where they occur**.  So in your example:

```
where bmi = weight / height ^ 2  
      (skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
```

...`(skinny, normal, fat)` is a pattern because it occurs on the **left-hand side** of the equals sign, and `(18.5, 25.0, 30.0)` is an expression because it's on the **right-hand side** of the equals sign.

There's a definite list of contexts in Haskell where patterns are allowed, so patterns are the things that appear in those contexts.  First context: the left-hand sides of a definition's equations.  This can be a top-level definition, or local definitions inside a `where` or `let`:

```
 -- Top level definition
 (pat1, pat2) = ...
   where
     -- Local definition in `where`
     (pat3:pat4:_) = let 
                        -- Local definition in `let`
                        Maybe pat5 = ...
                     in ...
```

Second context:  the left-hand side of a `->` in a `case` expression:

```
case expr of
  Just pat -> 2*a
  Nothing -> 42
```

Third context: the left-hand side of the `<-` in `do`-notation or list comprehensions:

```
example1 = do
  (pat1, pat2) <- ...
  ...

example2 = [f x y | (x, y) <- ...]
```

I might be missing some other context, but these are the major ones at least.

---

The other important concept here is that of a **data constructor**: a constant or operator in Haskell that serves two functions:

1. As an **expression** that can be used to construct values of its type;
2. As a **pattern** that can be used to deconstruct values of its type.

And again, whether a specific use of a data constructor counts as the former or the latter depends entirely on whether it's a "left-hand side" vs. a "right-hand side" use of it.

Answer (score -1):

(What follows is not strictly true; as Shumush points out, pattern matching can only be done with data constructors, not just any function. `(:)` and `Just` mentioned below are actual data constructors; the various comma functions don't appear to be, so I don't actually know how pattern matching with tuples work. Perhaps consider this as a coincidental analogy for how tuples pattern match.)

First, think about how pattern matching applies to lists, using the definition of `map` as an example.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x (map f xs)
```

Here, you can pattern match against a list because `(:)` is a function that produces a list from an element and another list. That is, `(x:xs)` can match `[1,2,3]` by binding 1 to `x` and `[2,3]` to `xs` because `(:) 1 [2, 3] = 1 : [2,3] = [1,2,3]`.

`(,)` is a function that produces a tuple:

```
> :t (,)
(,) :: a -> b -> (a, b)
```

so `(,) 1 2 = (1, 2)`. You can thus pattern match with `(,)` the same way you can with `(:)`:

```
(skinny, normal, fat) = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
```

(Definitions for `(,,) :: a -> b -> c -> (a, b, c)`, `(,,,)`, and a few more are provided by the Prelude.)

binds 18.5 to `skinny`, 25.0 to `normal`, and 30.0 to `fat` because

```
(,) 18.5 25.0 30.0 = (18.5, 25.0, 30.0)
```

Think of pattern matching as the opposite of function evaluation. Instead of applying a function to values to produce a new value, you "break apart" a value to get the operands used to produce that value.

Pattern matching can be done with *any* function call, which is why you can pattern match on things like `Maybe` values

```
-- From the Functor instance of Maybe
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Maybe a) -> (Maybe b)
fmap f Nothing = Nothing
fmap f (Just x) = f x
```

Since `Just :: a -> Maybe a` is a function (specifically, a data constructor), you can pattern match by binding the value wrapped in a `Maybe` created by `Just` to `x`.

Comment: But `(:)` and `(,)` are not functions. Functions can not be used in pattern matching, only constructors can because they "construct data" and do not "compute values".

Comment: Yes, they are functions. Type `:t (:)` in GHCI, for example, to see its type. Infix operators are simply functions whose names consist only of symbols. Where regular functions can be treated as infix operators by including them in backquotes (`fmap f [1,2]` is the same as `f \`fmap\` [1,2]`), infix operators can be treated as regular functions by enclosing them in parentheses.

Comment: `Just` is a constructor, but if you type `:t Just` you will have `Just :: a -> Maybe a`. Constructors can be defined as infix operators. You can define a list like this `data List a = [] | a : List a`.
Constructors are 'like' functions because they take some values and "compute" another value, but only constructors can be used in pattern matching.

You can't use `mktuple a b = (a, b)` for pattern matching. `a `mktuple` b = (1, 2)` is not valid

Comment: Yes, I forget the rule, though (they have to begin with `:`, I think?) `,` is a little weird, since `(,,)` isn't an infix operator so much as a ternary operator. You write `(,,) 1 2 3` or `(1, 2, 3)`, not `1 ,, 2 ,, 3`, so I think maybe in the case of `,`, pattern matching is a little bit of a special case, rather than a direct result of it being a constructor. While `Just` is an actual data constructor (`data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing`), I think `(,)` and family are just functions that *look* like constructors. I'll see if I can find the actual definition of the various tuple types.

Comment: In [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7086771/3360918) C. A. McCann explains that tuple constructors (used this way : `(1,2,3)` ) are syntaxic sugar, and therefore not implemented as `Maybe` or other data types could be.

Comment: OK, the comment that tuple syntax is built-in, like the `IO` action, is what I suspected. `(a, b, c)` isn't syntactic sugar for another Haskell expression; it just *is* the type of 3-element tuples defined by Haskell. `(,,)` is then just an ordinary function (not even an infix operator, really) that (currying aside) returns a `(a, b, c)`.